# unit tests not available anymore

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-2

i work on a asp.net mvc2 web project and trying to create some tests. Now i am getting the following error:

> no tests were run because no tests are loaded or the selected tests are disabled

Comment: Have you checked your Test classes & methods to have attributes `[TestClass()]` and `[TestMethod()]` accordingly?

Comment: That's a common problem with MSTest. Switch to a proper unit testing framework like xUnit.net or NUnit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved it, i created a new testproject and this works:)
thanks evyone.

Comment: @user603007: Can you edit this into your question please and delete this one? People dont provide answer's to self unless they really need to document an approach which is at variance to all the other given answers.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to .NET ;)

Simplest thing first - Please try to first rebuild and then reload the solution. Next, please try refreshing your vsmdi file under Solutions Items.
Please check the Test annotations are in place. One of these usually works

Comment: where are the vsmdi files? tried all the other stuff , still does not work:(

Comment: Select List of Tests in Test List Editor window and click refresh.

Comment: This has nothing to do with .NET. Please don't confuse MSTest with anything of that nature - it's plenty confused as it is.

Answer (score 0):

maybe your test list editor is empty.
if your test classes are covered with correct attributes like [testClass] and [testMethod]
and test doesn't run and are out of  the list, so your Project is not a TestProject.

Try to convert it to TestProject.
1. Open porject file outside of VS (with notePad)
2. Find (or add new) and replace ProjectTypeGuids string whith
{3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}

3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB - is a guid of test project type.
3. Save it and try.

[Source link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vststest/thread/29f9d88a-4b14-4d64-8d9b-5ab6e42cdca5)